# Why doesn't C++20 allow type-alias in a requires-expression?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, type-alias, requires-expression

```
#include <type_traits>

struct MyType { void operator [](int) const {} };

template<typename T>
concept IsMyType1 = requires(T obj)
{
    { obj[0] };
    using U = std::remove_cvref_t<T>; // error
    requires std::is_same_v<U, MyType>;
};

template<typename T>
concept IsMyType2 = requires(T obj)
{
    { obj[0] };
    requires std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, 
                            MyType>; // okay
};

int main() {}
```

**Why doesn't C++20 allow type-alias in a requires-expression?**

Comment: How would this be safely used?

Comment: Because a type alias is a statement, not an expression

Comment: But I think `IsMyType1` is obviously more expressive, and no ambiguity. @PatrickRoberts

Comment: [This](https://godbolt.org/z/WYEaYWjKx) seems to work for both the "error" and "okay" version - not sure if that's somthing you'd like to avoid.

Comment: Now it's ok, I have updated the source code. @TedLyngmo

Comment: @xmllmx Ok, I updated my comment.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Might be hijacked though [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3YzPW9e55)

Comment: @Jarod42 Ouch :-)